# Enable GD support in PHP

Tags: php, gd2

I'm trying to install pixelpost on an Apache server on windows. The installer is failing because:

> Pixelpost will not run if your PHP
>   installation is not compiled with the
>   GD graphics library.

I've added the following line to php.ini

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

But I still get the same error message. When I run `phpinfo()` I don't see any reference to GD, so I guess it really isn't installed. I searched for `php_gd2.dll` and it's in the `ext` subfolder of my PHP root dir.

I know nothing about PHP, so be gentle with me.

### Update

To answer the questions raised in the comments:

- I restarted Apache after modifying `php.ini`
- `php.ini` is in the root dir of my PHP installation `C:\php\php.ini`

---

Comment: Did you restart Apache after adding the line? Are you sure you're adding the right php.ini? If in doubt, do a `phpinfo()` to see for sure.

Comment: You must restart apache and also post the location of php.ini you edited

Comment: Relative path in extension_dir can cause Apache to look in its on folder, also additional dll's might be outside system path (er.. not in system32/ or environmental settings not changed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following are the steps for any `php` extension (on `MS-Windows`):

1. Give absolute path (not relative) to extensions directory [use forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`); I'm not too sure whether it's required to end the path with trailing slash.

   - e.g.: `extension_dir = c:/php5/ext`
2. Make sure `php` is referring your `php.ini`, now `php.ini` can be inside your `php` installation root dir.

   - If your changes to `php.ini` are reflected on `phpinfo()`, it's OK. If not, please refer to `INSTALL` file in `php` root dir.
3. Restart `apache` if you're binding `php` as a module to `apache`

Comment: using an absolute path for `extension_dir` fixed the problem - thanks!