# get and set image dpi

Tags: php, image

I need some info about images inside `cardimg` folder.

```
$arr = glob("../cardimg/*.jpg");
foreach ($arr as $item){
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($item);
    echo $width . '<br>';
    echo $height . '<br>';
}
```

Works fine for width and height, but don't know how to see if an image is 72 or 300 dpi?

my php is `7.0.20` and using

```
print_r(imageresolution($item));
```

result is error - `Call to undefined function`

Also is there a way to change `300dpi` to `72dpi` using php?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121890/change-resolution-of-image-from-72-to-25-dpi-in-php

Comment: You might check this out too..  http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php

Comment: @Joseph_J, it seems it's not possible to change dpi, but what about getting the dpi info only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is straight from PHP.net for imageresolution(). (PHP 7 >= 7.2.0)

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
print_r(imageresolution($im));
imageresolution($im, 300, 72);
print_r(imageresolution($im));
?>
```

This should get you what you need once you update your php version:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path));
print_r(imageresolution($im));
imagedestroy($im);
```

Here is a link on how to get gd library up and going.. I'm sure this varies on server setup hosted or not, I don't know.  But should help I imagine.

[Enable GD support in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646456/enable-gd-support-in-php)

Comment: please read my question again. I don't need to create any image, but get the info of existing ones.

Comment: @bonaca That's exactly what this does.  But it's only available in PHP 7 >= 7.2.0  "If none of the optional parameters is given, the current resolution is returned as indexed array. "

Comment: my php is 7.0.20 and using `print_r(imageresolution($item));` result is error - ` Call to undefined function`

Comment: is $item a an image object?  Let me update my answer.

Comment: If you're using PHP 7.0, then the function won't be available - as the answer says, it's only in PHP 7.2 (with the GD library enabled)

Comment: @iainn, I will update my php version. How to enable GD?

Comment: @bonaca It'll depend on your OS - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283199/enabling-installing-gd-extension-without-gd for a few pointers, but Google will be able to help